# JavaScript/jQuery hide form parts until previous is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I got stuck on the title so if someone can word it better then please do.

I have a pretty basic form using Bootstrap:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="age">Age</label>
    <br>
    I'm
    <a class="action age13" href="#">13-17</a>
    <a class="action age18" href="#">18-23</a>
    <a class="action age24" href="#">24+</a>
    years old
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="gender">Age</label>
    <br>
    I'm a
    <a class="action girl" href="#">girl</a>
    <a class="action guy" href="#">guy</a>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Link:** http://www.bootply.com/UmxZswdXUG

At the moment on load you can immediately see all 3 parts of the form, but I want to change it so that:

1. First you see only the username field and the submit button.
2. Once typing stops in username field, age field shows.
3. Once age field is selected, gender field shows.

Is this possible using JavaScript/jQuery etc.? If so where should I be looking for help with it?

Comment: Yes it's possible. You should look into dom appending child elements and removing them. If you want to use jquery look into .append() and .remove.. pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the .focusout() event for the username

```
$("#username").focusout(function() {

});
```

EDIT: It actually might be better to use .keyup() because .focusout will only call when you click outside the element.

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

You'd also need to give the div an id so inside the code above you can put

```
$("#myAgeField").show();
```

You can also use .hide();

To change the field you can do

```
$("#cboMyAge").change(function() {
    $("#myGenderField").show()
});
```

That should be enough JQuery to get it going, I've not tested this but it will look something on them lines.

Answer (score 1):

My first idea is to use onkeypress.

First hide them using css and than add something like this:

```
<element onkeypress="this.nextElementSibiling.style.display = 'block';">
```

So, when someone start typing, next element will show up....

Comment: To be honest, I was always taught to not use inline events, JQuery helps keep the HTML looking tidy by using the ID of an element, I think what you've shown is considered bad practice.

Comment: Which in my opinion is bad practice. Tidier and easier to use JQuery and keeps the design away from the code.

Comment: Dude, really? 
This is code that works and it's only meant to be starting point.
Will you do it inline, or define var x = document.getElementByWhateverIsBestForYou;
x.addEventListener....... this is not a production code, only answer on question that is focused on logic, not implementation.

Main idea is "use onkeypress, not onfocusout", else is too easy to be debated....

Answer (score 0):

These links should have everything you need:

http://api.jquery.com/show/

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Basically, you need to hide the elements you want to appear later, then bind focusout callback functions to the username and age inputs. These callback functions then use show to reveal the hidden elements. This can also be done with vanilla JS, but jQuery is easier/cleaner IMO.

Comment: I do not think `focusout` meets the requirements of "Once typing stops in username field, age field shows." Since all other form fields are hidden this would be kind of weird. Might have to do something with `setTimeout` and the `keypress` event

Comment: As far as I know, there aren't really any events that you can use to capture when ALL typing ends.  The closest one I can think of is `keyup` but that will fire after each key is entered

Comment: Maybe you could use `keyup` and then if a certain number of characters was entered, display the next field?

Comment: Yes that is correct you cannot read a users mind and know when typing has stopped lol. Thats why I said you would have to use `setTimeout` AND `keyup`

Comment: I don't think `setTimeout` is necessary.  Suppose a user types one character and then stops? That would feel kind of weird.  My suggestion would be to read the length of the string and if its greater than a certain threshold, display the next inputs

Comment: what if the string the entered never met that threshold?

Comment: Also a valid concern. If I was doing this, I'd open up the next input the second the user started typing, but that's just me

Comment: See my answer to this post on how it would be achieved using `setTimeout` and `keypress`

Answer (score 0):

I think `keypress` and using `setTimeout` might work best.

```
var t;
$('#username').on('keypress', function(){
  clearTimeout(t);

  t = setTimeout(function(){
    $('.form-group:eq(1)').fadeIn();
  }, 1000);
});
```

Of course you can change your `setTimeout` time to anything you think is best, I am using 1000ms.

Here is a demo (note: no fancy Bootstrap): [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/eghebse0/)